# I want a high A string for classical guitar

Tags: guitar

I want to buy a high A string for classical guitar. Anybody know how I can achieve that? I want to have an A standard tuning (so not E). Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to this site. Why not take the time to phrase a good question? ”I want to do this, how do I achieve this?“ is not really well placed here.

Comment: The best thing to do is to speak to a guitar technician about this but I would imagine that using the high five strings of a regular set, A to E then trying to find a very light gauge soft tension string for the high A might work. Two issues, that high string might have to be pulled tighter than the tension it is designed for to reach an A and the slots in your nut may be too wide for the thinner strings. Once again, all the more reason to talk to a luthier or technician.

Comment: How about placing a capo on the 5th fret?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one thing you might look into (but not do this without a consultation with someone who really understands this, which isn't me!) is whether a string intended for a different instrument might fit. For instance, the highest string on a 4-string banjo is an A, just the pitch you seem to want (and it seems nylon strings for banjos exist too, I've just checked). But a banjo is only about as long as a 3/4 guitar, so I'm really not sure how the tensions and everything would work out.

Answer (score 0):

The standard B tuning on a 7 string only tunes the G string a half tone down to a F#. This gives you in essence a B to B instrument with a high E added. This is basically a baritone tuning on a standard scale length guitar with a high E added.

You could if you wanted take that standard B tuning and tune everything down a further whole step. Turning the guitar into a standard A tuning with a high D string.

Although, it would probably needs some extra high tension strings to compensate for the lack of tension in the neck.

Comment: Hm, this opens an important question. I assumed the asker wants an a' (440 Hz) for their high A, whereas you seem to think they want an a (220 Hz). So, @asparagus - which one is it?

Comment: Ok, I only now saw the classical guitar part of the question.